# Searching Terms & Returning Shortest Finding

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an array of strings that can contain words or letters...

For example:

```
String[] s = new String[] { K W D A I B D W C D W S D B F A C E S D B C D E S A D B X }
```

And I have another string array that contains the terms I am looking for..

```
String[] terms = new String[] {A,B,C}
```

I would like to return the shortest subsequence from the "s" array that contains all of the terms in the terms array but it has to be a snippet and return the shortest subsequence in the s array that contains all of those terms. Sort of how google does when you search for a sequence of words and it returns articles that contains those words and has those worlds bold in the snippet.

I know there are several different algorithms that could be use to do this. But I would like to do this with O(n) algorithm.

How would you go about doing something like this?

Comment: Your example is very odd. Provided that all the items in `terms` are in `s`, just return `terms` itself. Or could `s` also contain, e.g. `TG`, and would then `{"K", "TG"}` be a valid result? Vice versa, if `terms` was `{"KB"}`, would then `{"K", "B"}` be a valid result?

Comment: I agree with @tobias_k here, the arrays you provide are very ambiguous to what you're trying to achieve. You should be more clear about what you're trying to achieve in terms of results, also it's worth noting that to achieve `O(n)` may be difficult depending on your goal, you may want to look at something like `Collection` here.

Comment: I updated my questions. And yes O(n) would be difficult to achieve here, so I am willing to be open to other algorithms as well

Comment: Still not entirely clear. Do you want a _subset_ or a _subsequence_? In your example, would `A I B D W C` be a solution?

Comment: If those are supposed to occur in exactly that order, you could just use a regular expression to match `A.*?B.*?C`.

Comment: Yes A I B D W C would be a solution

Comment: and then I would want the shortest subsequence

Comment: and yes it is subsequence

Comment: It is not clear what kind of array `s` is and what type of expression your letters are. I assume letters (e.g. `A` or `K`) are constants standing for Strings, right? Then `terms` is indeed an array of Strings, but `s` will not compile. Separate them by commas (if each constant is an element of the array) or join them by `+` if the array does contain only one element consisting of the concatenated constants.

Comment: @CoronA Yes I know. I just marked up the code and was too didnt write the quotation marks or the commas. But yes each term is a separate string